# Safari Extension: Display a local HTML, instead of the default or blank page, when the user opens a new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to port a simple Chrome extension to Safari extension. It should display a local HTML when the user opens a new tab, but the path to the file should not appear in the URL-bar.

The code for the Chrome Extension is:

**manifest.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "main.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

**main.html**

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    Hello World!
  </body>
</html>
```

In Safari, the close I get is to create a button on the toolbar an redirect to an URL.

How can I achieve the same functionality? I've tried to find examples, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be possible to do reliably. You can detect when a new tab is opened using the `open` event that is fired on `safari.application` or on a `SafariBrowserWindow` object, but then you have to make sure the new tab is not going to have a page loaded into it right away. That you can do by listening for a `beforeNavigate` event on the new tab...but then there are complications.

If the tab remains truly blank, no `beforeNavigate` event will be fired right away, so you can use a timeout to stop listening for the event and then proceed with loading the page of your choice. But new tabs may not remain blank. They can show the Top Sites page (the default behavior), they can show the user-specified home page, or they can show the page that is loaded in the previous tab.

In the home-page and same-page cases, a `beforeNavigate` event will be fired on the new tab, and its `url` property's value will be the URL to be loaded. Whether or not to hijack these types of new tab and load your own page into them is up to you.

In the Top Sites case, a `beforeNavigate` event will be fired on the new tab, but its `url` property will be `null`. So you might think you can detect that and then load the page of your choice in the new tab. However, there is a problem, because this same behavior (a `beforeNavigate` event with a null url) happens when any extension opens one of its own pages in a new tab. Therefore, if you were to hijack all tabs with a null `beforeNavigate` URL, you would make it impossible for other extensions to open their own pages.